# Explain Plan in PostgreSQL does not execute when provided with placeholders unlike Oracle

Tags: java, postgresql, sql-execution-plan, explain

**Example at Oracle**:

```
explain plan for select * from sample_table where column_name = :1
```

This will return query plan with detailed steps and cost in a tabular form.

**Example at PostgreSQL**

```
explain (format yaml) select * from sample_table where column_name = $1
```

This will end up returning an error which asks for parameters.

```
explain (format yaml) select * from sample_table where column_name = $$$$
```

This will end up returning an error for timestamp and integer

```
explain (format yaml) select * from sample_table where column_name = null
```

This will end up returning incomplete plan with no filter information as we are passing null.

Note: Aware that it might be looking for actual parameters.

Could anyone please guide on any appropriate value which could be used for character varying, text, integer and timestamp that could give a complete plan? Point is we cannot pass the actual parameters due to data concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not so easy to get a generic plan in PostgreSQL. You can do it by setting `plan_cache_mode = force_generic_plan`, creating a prepared statement and calling `EXPLAIN EXECUTE ...` while supplying NULL values.

You can find the procedure described in [my article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/explain-that-parameterized-statement/).

I have [submitted a patch](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/42/3962/) for PostgreSQL v16 that adds that functionality to core. If you want that to happen, you could review the patch or express your interest on the mailing list.

Comment: That's why I use the `unknown` pseudo-type for the parameters and NULL for the arguments.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz! The article provided me insights on the issue and helped me proceed with the detailed steps you provided. The solution worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the execution plan for a specific value if you use  a prepared statement:

```
prepare pstmt(integer) 
as 
select * 
from sample_table 
where column_name = $1;
```

Then get the plan for a specific value using:

```
explain (analyze, buffers) 
execute pstmt(42);
```

Comment: Ours is a Java application. 

As this plan executer is implemented in a different module and does not have access to parameters for dynamic queries formed throughout the application, passing 
`execute pstmt(**42**);` 
would be a challenge. Understanding data types and assigning particulars is another challenge. 

Looking for generic values or way to form generic plan.